# How do I overwrite a template of base application from my own bundle?

Tags: php, symfony, symfony4

I use Symfony 4.4 and have written my own bundle. From this bundle I want to overwrite or extend an existing Twig-Template of the base application. So e.g. add a new line at the bottom of the Content block.
I have already made several attempts, unfortunately without success. Most examples go in the other direction, overwriting bundle templates. Do you have any tips how I can solve the problem?  Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

For overwrite a template from a bundle you can following this [link](https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/override.html) from Symfony Doc.

Comment: Sorry, i don‘t want to overwrite my bundles templates. I want to overwrite or extend some templates of my base app where the bundle is included.